# Cairo won't work with Gtk#

Tags: c#, monodevelop, gtk#

I have installed Cairo on my computer, yet when I try to use it in gtk# I still get, 'The type or namespace name 'Cairo' could not be found. Are you missing an assembly reference?'

Is there something else I need to do before I can use Cairo with Gtk# in monodevlop?

Answer (score 0):

To use cairo with gtk# you need a reference to mono.cairo dll.